# Operator overloading for max in C++

Tags: c++, class, operators

I am implementing a new variable type (NewType) with arithmetic operators (+, -, *, /) and std::max overloaded. Although the arithmetic operators work, the max function has got some problem. Could someone provide some pointers what I am missing?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class NewType {
private:
    float val;

public:
    NewType(float v) { val = v; }
    // Arithmetic operators
    friend NewType operator+(const NewType &c1, const NewType &c2);
    friend NewType operator-(const NewType &c1, const NewType &c2);
    friend NewType operator*(const NewType &c1, const NewType &c2);
    friend NewType operator/(const NewType &c1, const NewType &c2);

    float GetVal() { return val; }

    float max(const NewType &lhs, const NewType &rhs) { return lhs.val > rhs.val ? lhs.val : rhs.val; }
    };

// Arithmetic Operations
NewType operator+(const NewType &c1, const NewType &c2) { return NewType(c1.val + c2.val); }
NewType operator-(const NewType &c1, const NewType &c2) { return NewType(c1.val - c2.val); }
NewType operator*(const NewType &c1, const NewType &c2) { return NewType(c1.val * c2.val); }
NewType operator/(const NewType &c1, const NewType &c2) { return NewType(c1.val / c2.val); }


int main() {

    NewType a = 10.2;
    NewType b = 8.4;
    NewType c = a+b;

    cout << c.GetVal() << std::endl;

    NewType d = max(a,b);
    cout << d.GetVal() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `friend float max(...`

Comment: You're calling `std::max`, not the `max` defined in your class. `std::max` uses `operator<` by default, which you haven't implemented.

Comment: Maybe its time to quit using this: `using namespace std;`

Comment: @drescherjm It's _always_ time to remove `using namespace std;`.

Comment: Declare max as friend and define the max  outside of the class as did for operator overloading , The current implementation of yours calls the std::max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've implemented `max` as a non-static member function. You would call it like this:

```
NewType a(0.0f), b(1.0f), c(2.0f);
NewType d = a.max(b, c);
```

Notice that `a` is not actually needed for this operation at all, except for the fact that you declared `max` as a non-static member function. One solution would be to make it a non member function.

```
// outside of the class body
float max(const NewType &lhs, const NewType &rhs) {
    return lhs.GetVal() > rhs.GetVal() ? lhs.GetVal() : rhs.GetVal();
}
```

Another (better, imo) solution would be to overload `operator<` for your class, and then your class will automatically work with `std::min` and `std::max`, as well as a host of algorithms and containers from the standard library.

```
// member version, inside the class
bool operator<(const NewType& rhs) const {
    return val < rhs.val;
}

// non-member version, outside the class
bool operator<(const NewType& lhs, const NewType& rhs) {
    return lhs.GetVal() < rhs.GetVal();
}
```

On a side note, make `GetVal` const.

```
float GetVal() const { return val; }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Putting the max outside according to what you said works fine. However the other idea does not seem to be working (overloading < for std::max).

`#include <iostream>
class NewType {
private:
 float val;
public:
 NewType(float v) { val = v; }
 bool operator<(const NewType &rhs) const { return val < rhs.val; }

 float GetVal() const { return val; }
 };
bool operator<(const NewType& lhs, const NewType& rhs) { return lhs.GetVal() < rhs.GetVal();}

int main() {
 NewType a = 10.2;
 NewType b = 8.4;
 std::cout << std::max(a,b) << std::endl;
 return 0;
}`

Comment: @smjee: Note that `std::max` returns the same type that was passed to it (this is the natural thing to do), so it will return a `NewType` object if passed 2 `NewType` objects. Whereas your max function returns a float. The output `operator<<` is overloaded for `float`, but not your type. So you can either provide that overload, or use `std::max(a, b).GetVal()` to get a float from the result of `std::max`.

Comment: @smjee: Well, while I wait for that, another problem is that you've overloaded `operator<` twice. Once as a member function, and once as a non-member function. Perhaps I wasn't clear, but I was just showing you the two possibilities. You need to pick one, not use both. Otherwise you have an ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks! Solved the problem :)